# Php Email is not being received

Tags: php, html, forms, email

I am using basic php mail function to send an email. But due to unknown reason the is not being received. I am not able to find any issue with the code. Any help? thanks in advance.

[Website Link](http://www.liguriacucine.com/contattaci.php)

**PHP**

```
<?php
// display form if user has not clicked submit
if (!isset($_POST["submit"])) {
  ?>
      <?php
} else {    // the user has submitted the form
  // Check if the "from" input field is filled out
  if (isset($_POST["contact_email"])) {
    $from = $_POST["contact_email"]; // sender
    $subject = $_POST["contact_name"];
    $message = $_POST["contact_message"];
    // message lines should not exceed 70 characters (PHP rule), so wrap it
    $message = wordwrap($message, 70);
    // send mail
    mail("email@example.com",$subject,$message,"From: $from\n");
    echo "Thank you for sending us feedback";
  }
}
?>
```

**FORM**

```
<form id="contactForm" class="cmxform" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>" >
        <strong>Usa il modulo sottostante per inviarci un messaggio email:</strong>
        <div>
          <label for="contact_name">Nome </label>
          <em>(obbligatorio, almeno 2 lettere)</em><br />
          <input id="contact_name" name="contact_name" size="30" class="required" minlength="2" value="" required="required" />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label for="contact_email">E-Mail </label>
          <em>(obbligatorio)</em><br />
          <input id="contact_email" name="contact_email" size="30" type="email"  class="required email" value="" />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label for="contact_phone">Telefono </label>
          <em>(opzionale)</em><br />
          <input id="contact_phone" name="contact_phone" size="14" type="number" class="phone" value="" maxlength="14" />
          <label for="contact_ext">interno </label>
          <input id="contact_ext" name="contact_ext" size="5" type="tel" class="ext" value="" maxlength="5" />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label for="contact_message">Il tuo commento </label>
          <em>(obbligatorio)</em><br />
          <textarea id="contact_message" name="contact_message" cols="70" rows="7" class="required"></textarea>
        </div>

        <div>
          <input name="submit" class="submit" type="submit" value="Invia"/>
        </div>

      </form>
```

Comment: Have you checked the error logs?

Comment: Have you done **ANY** basic debugging yourself? Liking checking mail()'s return value, checking your mail server logs, blah blah blah? Remember that PHP doesn't deliver mail, it just hands it over to a mail server. It's not PHP's job to tell you if the mail can't be delivered after the letter got dropped into the mailbox.

Comment: ...one of the `blah`'s equals "check spam folder".

Comment: not able to find any error on debuging.. also spam folder is empty...

Comment: Sidenote: You don't have a "type" set for `<input id="contact_name" name="contact_name"` and for `<input id="contact_ext" name="contact_ext"` <= part of the debugging process. ;-)

Comment: if you are using hotmail, they are very strict... you will have to use every single header possible lol

Comment: @Fred-ii- Shouldn't it work anyway? The default type is text I think even if you don't specify it but of course you should

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek I have seen a few cases (in the past) where Email wouldn't come in (or processed), if there were no "type" set to a form element.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thanks for info. I'll remember it just in case

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek You're welcome Marcin. Forms can be tricky at times and can be a mix of one or many (contributing) factors.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php
> Note:
> When sending mail, the mail must contain a From header. This can be set with the additional_headers parameter, or a default can be set in php.ini.
> Failing to do this will result in an error message similar to Warning: mail(): "sendmail_from" not set in php.ini or custom "From:" header missing. The From header sets also Return-Path under Windows.

Comment: @Mr.TK Good point +1. OP is using `"From: $from\n")` but that stands at failing.

Comment: i tried adding input type="text" but still not working

Comment: I suggest you try a simple and basic `mail()` test in a seperate script using proper headers (as outlined above) and see if you get mail. If you're running this from a hosted site, make sure mail is available for you to use, and if running from your own computer, making sure that it is properly configured.

Comment: @Fred-ii- thanks i will check this out... website link is mentioned and it is hosted where every thing is configured.

Comment: You're welcome. I tested your code and it worked fine for me. Beside the fact that 90% of the info for the form didn't come in properly but that's beside the fact. (Probably due to the mixing type="text")

Comment: @Fred-ii- i have windows hosting... any possible issue with that?

Comment: @Firebug That could be a factor. I suggest you contact your hosting provider to ask them which mailer (sendmail) you should be using. Some have "blat", "Qmail" etc. I'm on Linux myself using PHP's `mail()` function. You may have to use `SMTP` since some hosts don't offer `mail()` for security purposes.

Comment: You could also look into PHPMailer and Swiftmailer.

Answer (score 1):

PHP Mail returns boolean. True if message been sended by mailer, false - if not. (it not means that message has been recieved, only sended).
try:

```
var_dump(mail("email@example.com",$subject,$message,"From: $from\n"));
```

Comment: If false, than you have some problems with your php mailer. Then contact your hoster...

Comment: I have talked to hosting provider there nothing with the code it was hosting issue;
On a windows server the php mailer function does not work. You can sent only the authenticated email. Otherwise you can move to a linux based server where you should be able to use that function.

Comment: YEP. Try this: http://email.about.com/od/emailprogrammingtips/qt/PHP_Email_SMTP_Authentication.htm